# Can't locate packages vesta, vesta-nginx and vesta-php

Tags: apt

I have a problem with installing Vesta Control Panel on my DigitalOcean VPS on Ubuntu 12.10. The system is updated and upgraded.

I got the following error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.vestacp.com/quantal/dists/quantal/vesta/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vesta
E: Unable to locate package vesta-nginx
E: Unable to locate package vesta-php
Error: apt-get install failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package doesn't exist on apt.vestacp.com, or maybe your version isn't supported or you haven't updated your apt database. In your specific case Ubuntu (it is 12.10) is not supported, but at the web-site of Vesta it was added in list of supporting.

Comment: On site of Vesta Control Panel supporting version of Ubuntu 12.10 exists.
But where I can find missing packages, if there is no on apt.vestacp.com?
My apt database is on date.

Comment: Did you update your apt database after adding the ppa?

Comment: try sudo apt-get update

Comment: There is no updated or upgraded files after apt-get update

Comment: Then perhaps they don't support 64bit or something. You really should ask them. It's not an Ubuntu issue. However, apt-get update isn't supposed to install upgrades. It simply updates the database in order to let Ubuntu know what's available. Try installing the package again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error after running below command before `bash vst-install.sh`.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gnupg
```